# Event object IsRecurrence2 field is not visible in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning-apps, fields, standard-objects, flexipages

I have a Event record page. I am creating recuring event. To create recurring event salesforce had provided checkbox field called **IsRecurrence2** on Event object. I want to set visibility criteria in lighting app builder but **IsRecurrence2** is not available.

[image]

I am logged in as System admin and have all the access for field and object. Any idea why I can not use **IsRecurrence2** field in Visibility criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to replicate and this seem to be WAD. Since [Repeat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm)(IsRecurrence2) field is read-only and is defaulted on create, IsRecurrence2 field contains a derived value and wont be available on visibility filter criteria.

[image]